# How to send something from php page to java application?

Tags: java, php, get, request

I'm making an admin panel in php to control my Java app.
I know to how send a request in java to php.  For example,
I have this link:

`myPage.com/admin/statusServers&id=10` (this page prints f.e "OK")

In Java, I can read this "`OK`", but how do I send `"request"` from php to java?
Something like this:

```
myPage.com/admin/resetApp&pass=312&user=123
```

My intention is for the app to receive this, validate the user-pass combination, and then reset something.
Do I need to make an infinite loop with 1-sec delay to check for requests, or something like this?

Comment: Can you explain where that java and where that php runs? On the same server? And why do you want a php frontend to a java application? When both things run on the same machine they have more ways to communicate.

Comment: php and java run on the same machine

Comment: Fix grammar, spelling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

java and php are on the same machine ?

## PHP TO JAVA

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

So, I have a very basic test set up to see if i can send data from a php web page to a java app running on the same server.

The java app is dead simple, it just listens on a TCP socket for data

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            connectionSocket.close();
         }
      }
}
```

**Method 1**

```
$host = "tcp://localhost"; 
$port = 6789;
$data = 'test' . PHP_EOL; 
$errstr = '';
$errno = '';

if ( ($fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3) ) === FALSE)
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
else {
    print 'SUCCESS!<br />';
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    while (! feof($fp)) {
      echo fgets($fp, 4096);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Method 2**

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$port = 6789;
$data = 'test';

if ( ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === FALSE )
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
else 
{
    echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...<br>";
    if ( ($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === FALSE )
        echo "socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    else {
        echo "Sending data...<br>";
        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
        echo "OK<br>";

        echo "Reading response:<br>";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
            echo $out;
        }
    }
    socket_close($socket);      
}
```

**EDIT**

## JAVA TO PHP

There are many ways to do it
I would think any system used to invoke an action command from php

```php
if( isset($_GET["user"]) && isset($_GET["pass"]) ){
  echo system("java myjavaprogram . " .$_GET["user"])
  // Then args will be an array containing the strings $_GET["user"]
}
```

and the java program receive the command and fired action

```java
public static void main(String [] args) {
   String user = args[0]; // user
   // etc.. etc 
}
```

You can also use curl parea make any request from php

```php
if( isset($_GET["user"]) && isset($_GET["pass"]) ){

    $ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1:8080/servlet");
    $fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I hope I've helped